# Any weedkillers that are safe for Catnip and Catmint?

Tags: weed-control, shrubs, weeds

I have an area full of catmint and catnip that I'd like to spray to control for weeds.  Unfortunately, all the "*Kills weeds and not your lawn*" products I could find will target for catmint/catnip.  Anyone know of any safe herbicides that won't kill my catmint/catnip?

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to be spraying poison on a plant you're going to be feeding to your cat?

Comment: @nick012000 - why do you think the questioner (a) has a cat, and (b) intends to feed the plants to the cat?

Comment: @Peter4075 Why else would you grow catnip? It's kitty drugs.

Comment: @nick012000  RHS say: "These dependable perennials produce a profusion of usually lavender-blue flowers over a long season from late-spring to late-summer. The tough plants are easy to grow and low maintenance, use them in borders with other perennials or as an informal edging as an alternative to lavender. Trim after flowering to neaten and encourage further flower production." Also: "The appeal of these plants to cats is well known, and some cat toys are stuffed with dried leaves. While many cats can flatten plants in their excitement, some are more disdainful or just have a little chew."

Comment: They are great for attracting hummingbirds too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Weedkillers for soft green growth are divided between those that will kill through the leaves, any type of leaf, and those  that kill in the same way but leave lawn grass largely unharmed. There is no formulation that will leave your  catnip untouched - its just another broader leaved plant to a weedkiller.

The area looks to be quite small and there isn't a huge amount of exposed soil -weeding by hand using a hand fork or border fork wouldn't take very long, if you are able to do it. Alternatively, you can just apply weedkiller such as glyphosate to the green growth of plants/weeds you don't want, taking care not to  get any on those you do.

Comment: Use glyphosate at recommended concentration, with an assistant right next to you with a hose ready to wash off overspray instantly.